# Visual Studio: c# interactive shell window

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there a way to use the C# interactive shell window (from the Roslyn CTP) outside of VS? Or is there something similar to it that is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several years (ugh!) there is finally something in this space! [CShell](http://cshell.net). From the site:

> CShell is an interactive C# scripting environment. It allows you to
>   use C# without any fluff right in a console like environment caled a
>   read-eval-print-loop (REPL). Your code is directly evaluated and
>   executed in a shell window, no separate executable has to be compiled
>   and then run in a different process. More elaborate code can be
>   written in a C# script and then evaluated as one file, only one line,
>   or a selection. Then, your results can be easily dumped to HTML (like
>   LINQPad) or viewed as a data grid or plotted to a chart.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 13):

Right now, the interactive window only works inside Visual Studio. Roslyn exposes a scripting API which the interactive window uses, so you *really* want an interactive window running somewhere else, feel free to write it!

Comment: :( F# has `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsi.exe"`

Comment: That is what I did :), see my answer below for the links

Comment: Does it come build in in VS 2015 RTM?

Comment: No, it didn't make it into Visual Studio 2015 RTM. I am happy to report it's being worked on again, though, so stay tuned!

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, the C# Interactive window uses several Visual Studio components (such as the VS Editor), so it cannot be hosted outside of VS. As Jason Malinowski said, you can create a quick-and-dirty Interactive window outside of VS pretty easily using the [Roslyn Scripting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh543925). Also, if you're looking to evaluate code outside of VS, you can create a C# Script file (.csx), add top-level code just as you can in the Interactive window, and run it with the rcsi.exe binary that ships with the Roslyn CTP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick Example, pretty minimal though. Don't support blocks {}

http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/10/c-vnext-roslynan-introduction-and-quick.html

Answer (score 1):

csi.exe is the command-line version of C# interactive. It's shipped in the box with Visual Studio. Type csi from a Developer Command prompt.